# custom post type get_posts() function not work

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types, plugin-development, query-posts, get-posts

```
$orders = get_posts(array(
  'post_type' => 'lp_order',
));
foreach ($orders as $order) {
  // get all order data code 
}
```

1. This the code I will try to **learnpress plugin** order post type front end display but it's not working I also check his capability.

   please suggest me I am a beginner in WordPress so no more ideas.
2. I try a different method like this:

```php
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'lp_order',
)

$tech_posts = new WP_Query($args);
if ($tech_posts->have_posts()) :
  while ($tech_posts->have_posts()) : $tech_posts->the_post();
    //order code
  endwhile;
endif;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it is not working"? Don't you get any posts or what is the problem?. Can you verify that the `lp_order` post type really exists? Try checking the return value from `get_post_types()` and update your question with this information.

Comment: yes brother i also check @Cyclonecode